# Page reloads, URL suffixed with "/?", after submit event - canonical solutions need not apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I'm following along with the simple chat app tutorial on socket.io, and I'm at the point where a snippet of jQuery on the page, when the form element fires a "submit" event, emits a "message" event which should be detected and logged by the server running locally. Except it isn't - the page reloads instead. I know it does because

- the command prompt running the server displays the same behavior as I just programmed it to display when a user reloads the page (logging "user has connected/disconnected") - this was part of the tutorial.
- the page's URL is suddenly suffixed with "/?", possibly implying it expects some query parameters which nothing in the code provides.

None of the apparently canonical solutions work:

- changing the button's type to "button" isn't an option, because the Enter key has to remain usable to submit the user's chat message.
- the sample code from the tutorial already contains `return false;`
- giving the `.submit()` function an `event` parameter and doing `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` doesn't work either

I'm stumped and beyond frustrated. There is a reason for this behavior and I want to know what the hell it is. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

**index.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var socket = io();

      $('form').submit(function(e){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
    </script>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a document.ready function since you are trying to bind the event handler before the element exists

```
 <script>

  var socket = io();
$(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');        
  });
})
</script>
```